# Hypermedia vs Graph Database

Tags: database, database-design

I was wondering if anyone could answer this question.

> What is the difference between a
>   Hypermedia managed database and a
>   Graph managed database?

From what my understanding is, that a Graph is a type of Hypermedia database that uses a graph structure to link nodes.

Would this be right, I am still a bit confused about it all.

Also there is a difference in that one uses NO SQL?

What other differences are there between them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A graph database is a kind of NoSQL database that uses graph structures with nodes, edges, and properties to represent and store information.

whereas

Hypermedia DB is an approach to data management that organized data as a network of nodes linked in any pattern the user specifies.
The World Wide Web can be thought of as a Hypermedia databases spread across millions of independent computing systems.

Basically the Hypermedia db is any kind of database used for the purpose of storing multimedia web pages. In a Hypermedia database, data is stored online and it can be accessed by multiple users, simultaneously.

Hypermedia db is spread over across multiple systems and these `systems are linked` within the network. The term `linked` refers the interconnection of systems. So there is a difference between Graph database and Hypermedia database.

References:[Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database),[Different Database Strokes for Different Database Folks](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/94426.aspx)